# Refresh JPanel with another values

Tags: java, jpanel

Today I started to learn Java and I'm stuck here, I don't know how to refresh the panel using a button. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class App {

public static int STR = 0, aPower = 0, sPower = 0, INT = 0, STA = 0, DEF = 0;

private static void GenerateStatus(){
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    STR = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);
    aPower = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);
    sPower = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);
    INT = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);
    STA = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);
    DEF = randomGenerator.nextInt(50);
}

private static void FirstTimeInGame() {
    String[] items = {"Warrior", "Mage", "Druid", "Scout"};
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(items);
    JTextField Name = new JTextField();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    GenerateStatus();

    panel.add(new JLabel("Name", SwingConstants.CENTER));
    panel.add(Name);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Class", SwingConstants.CENTER));
    panel.add(combo);
    panel.add(new JLabel("Stats", SwingConstants.CENTER));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Strength           " + STR));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Attack Power  " + aPower));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Spell Power     " + sPower));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Intellect            " + INT));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Stamina            " + STA));
    panel.add(new JLabel("Armor               " + DEF));

    String[] buttons = {"Create!", "Randomize!", "Cancel"};

    int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            panel,
            "Welcome",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null,
            buttons,
            buttons[2]
            );

    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        System.out.println(combo.getSelectedItem()
                + " " + Name.getText());
    }
    else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        GenerateStatus();
        panel.validate();
        panel.repaint();

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("CANCEL");
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FirstTimeInGame();
}
}
```

Function GenerateStatus() generate random numbers. When I press the button 'Randomize!' the window is closing.
[image]

Anyone can help me? Please?

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't seem relevant to the problem...

Comment: I want when I press the button 'Randomize!' to refresh the 'Stats' values. How do I do that?

Comment: How are we supposed to know? You haven't shown us any code with anything to do about "Stats".

Comment: I updated it! Check again please. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just adding the JLabels to a panel, you need to store them in class level members.
When you click a button, you need to change the text in the existing labels.

Near this:

```
public static int STR = 0, aPower = 0, sPower = 0, INT = 0, STA = 0, DEF = 0;
```

Add

```
private JLabel strLabel;
```

Then  `panel.add(new JLabel("Strength           " + STR));` becomes

```
strLabel = new JLabel("Strength           " + STR);
panel.add(strLabel);
```

Now you can change the text of `strLabel` from somewhere else.

Comment: Can you write a part of code? I donno how to do this, first time in java :)

Comment: But, when I press "Randomize!" the window is closing, how to make it still stay up?

Comment: I don't think there is enough code here to tell... What do your prints tell you? what parts of the code are executed?